# Make executable erlang program on the Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, shell, erlang, compilation, executable

I'm very new to Erlang. I've tried now several hours to find out how to run my sample scripts without the Erlang Shell.

I have installed Erlang with Mac Ports, and I can access the Shell, write Scripts etc.

But I try to run my program in the Mac Terminal.

On this page [1] they are using ecc and elink. I don't have these programs in my installation.

Can you please provide me a way, how I can solve my problem?

Thanks and regards

chris

[1] http://www.sics.se/~joe/sae.html

Comment: Stand-Alone Erlang is basically obsolete. It is based on Erlang R9 and hasn't been updated since. Maybe someday someone will revive it, but until then, it's best to go with one of the answers below and ignore SAE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
```

at the beginning of your script and make it executable (as @nomulous said):

```
chmod u+x myscript
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
./myscript
```

if it is in your current directory, or by giving its relative or full path otherwise, *e.g.*:

```
~/Desktop/myscript
```

*Reference:* [the page you gave](http://www.sics.se/~joe/sae.html) section **Erlang Scripts**

Comment: Don't forget the `main/1` function. [Full escript documentation here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html).

Answer (score 1):

If your script is not executable, it won't run outside of the shell.

To make it executable, use `chmod +x your_script_here`.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebar (https://bitbucket.org/basho/rebar/wiki/Home) :)

Comment: I don't see that rebar does anything in regards to helping you start and stop an Erlang program. As far as I can see, it's a build, test and release system, not a runtime system.

Comment: rebar's generated node you can stop, start, restart